# What's the fastest way to solve this inequality?

Tags: inequality

$|x^2-3x+2|>|x|+1$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decompose $x^{2}-3x+2$ into linear factors and make cases for the sign of the left handside, be careful about $x$, because it will be included in the cases.

Comment: Fastest? use Mathematica or MATLAB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$.

Thus

- If $x \in (-\infty, 0]$ the inequality becomes....
- If $x \in (0, 1]$ the inequality becomes....
- If $x \in (1, 2]$ the inequality becomes....
- If $x \in (2,  \infty]$ the inequality becomes....

A faster way would be to draw the two graphs, since they are easy to draw.

Comment: Isn't sufficient calculate only what the inequality becomes if x>=0 or x<0?

Comment: @user40907 And what is $|x^2-3x+2|$ when $x \geq 0$?

Comment: It's $x^2-3x+2$

Comment: @user40907 But that is negative when $x \in (1,2)$. How can the absolute value be negative?

Comment: I agree with you. So the left handside is negative only when $x in (1,2)$. But how can I set up all the solutions?

Comment: @user40907 Well you have 4 possibilities, and in each of them yo know what each $|. |$ is. Solve the inequality in each of the 4 cases.